# fsWriteFile refuses to write

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have implemented a fsWrite function in my algorithm that outputs all of the generated data to a .txt file after it prints everything to the terminal window. I am currently testing my package with npm pack in a local environment and everything seems to work, except for the file. The file is supposed to be written to a 'output' folder in the same directory but it does not work.

```
  const outputName = `dominion_output_${date.toDateString()}-${date.toLocaleTimeString()}.txt`;
  const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, "output", outputName);

  const data = `${intrPrint}${resultPrint}${customPrint}${existingPrint}${shotPrint}${totalShotPrint}${lengthPrint}${shotParaPrint}${depthParaPrint}${postPrint}`;

  fs.writeFile(outputPath, data, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(
      `Data has been written to ${outputName}.\nPlease check the 'output' folder within the q3dominion directory.\n`
    )};
  });
};

module.exports = dominion;
```

I have tried checking the documentation and googling but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: By the way, I am not getting an error in any way and everything runs as expected, except for the file not being generated. So there's some kind of oversight in my code but I can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: So you get the message `Data has been written to ...` logged to the console?

Comment: Yes, I did get that message. I wanted the file to go to an output folder in the actual node module folder, but that seemed to give errors. Now I changed the folders location to the root of the project and now it works like a charm! Path also gave me some errors and turned out I didn't even need it